# Does conda env export use pip?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I successfully created a Conda environment at path `./xxxxx/conda_env/xyz`. I am also able to activate that environment.

However, `conda env export -p /xxxxx/conda_env/xyz` fails (I have the same environment activated), giving error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxxxx/conda_env/xyz/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli'
```

#### Does `conda env export` uses pip? If so, why?

---

P.S. I do have `pip` installed

```
$ conda list --explicit | grep pip
http://anaconda:8080/conda/anaconda/linux-64/pip-20.0.2-py36_1.tar.bz2
```

Comment: can you add the output of `conda list -n base requests` and `conda list -n base pip`

Comment: @cel Thank you cel. Sorry for the late reply. For `requests`, the base environment has `requests=2.19.1=py27_0`. For `pip` it would be `pip=10.0.1=py27_0`. The channel column is empty for both.

Answer (score 1):

Your command doesn't make sense:

```
conda env export -p /xxxxx/conda_env/xyz
```

should probably be

```
conda env export -p /xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/conda_env
```

But it seems this command is deprecated anyhow. According to [Exporting the environment.yml file](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment) your should instead use

```
conda activate conda_env
conda env export > environment.yml
```

However, it's totally fine to **pip install packages** from *pypi.org* into a conda environment that are not available on *anaconda.org*. And ideally pip packages should also end up in the environments.yml like

```
name: conda_env
channels:
  - default
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip:
    - tables
```

So no surprise that pip is involved here.

Comment: The location should not affect it. The prefix option exists so that envs can be installed in non-default locations. Also, it is unlikely the `--name` or `--prefix` flags will ever go unsupported or become deprecated; the docs show the simplest way of doing things, whereas the OP shows a valid advanced usage.

Comment: ... but the questioner has problems with the "advanced usage" - if he is still interested to follow-up his question. Rather looks like a stupid mistake.

Comment: the traceback indicates the environment is correctly specified (not a stupid mistake); the line used to invoke the export is not "nonsense".

Comment: So what's your problem then?

Comment: @merv Thanks. Yes, I don't believe my syntax is erroneous. I will post an update to the comment in my question section.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for explaining the pip part. That makes sense. 
My understanding is that `conda env export` will export the **currently activated** environment, whereas `conda env export -p /xx/yy` will export the environment at **that particular location**. Unfortunately the first option doesn't work for me due to the problem I described above.

Comment: The problem for `conda env export`, without the `-p` option is https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1935 which seems like a long standing problem. The error is `Error: '/' not allowed in environment name: xxx`